# array_set - escape variable to allow fullstops

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im using `array_set` to create a array with value to use on a report.

the problem I have is the the `$key` variable used to create the dynamic keys in the array sometimes has some fullstop chars in the name, which causes the key added to be a multi dimensional array.

the value of `{$this->totalmonths}` in this example is `OUTCOME`

e.g. Im addin in `$key` a value that is `remained_on_unit`
and that is added fine as `[0]['OUTCOME_remained_on_unit'] = 1`

But sometimes there are some value that has fullstops.
e.g. `$key` is equal to `moved_to_I.C.U`, which results in
`[0]['OUTCOME_I'][C][U] = 1`

How do I escape `$key` to allow for fullstops? bellow is my line of code.

`array_set($months, "{$this->totalmonths}.$key", $totalcount+1)`

Comment: **morne**, according to the PHP Array Documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), the function `array_set`, does not exist. Could you update your question to be more specific as where this function comes from, for example? (Google gives me Laravel, but still)

Comment: are you using laravel framework? because array_set is not exists in php but exists in laravel

Comment: @BilalAhmed yes, its Laravel

Comment: then add laravel tags in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected functionality of [`array_set`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-set) (assuming you're using Laravel).

> The array_set function sets a value within a deeply nested array using "dot" notation:

To achieve what you're after:

```
//$this->totalmonths = 'OUTCOME'
//$key = moved_to_I.C.U
//$this->totalmonths . $key = 'OUTCOMEmoved_to_I.C.U'
$months[$this->totalmonths . $key] = $totalcount+1;
```

Comment: Richard, is this answer correct? PHP Arrays don't read dots as nested layers, this will be read as an index key.

Comment: @Rafael - The OP asks for: _"How do I escape $key to allow for fullstops?"_ which means that the OP doesn't want to read the dots as nested layers. So this is correct.

Comment: I see... ok, I thought that was an oversimplified solution but I overthought the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Morne, considering your example, you don't need to escape the `$key` variable. If the **dots** are contained in it, you can just concatenate like you are already doing and Laravel [array_set()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-set) should do the rest.

If you just want to set the key of any nested element, you will need the fullpath until the element concatenated with dots as a **string**.

So if you want the value of `['OUTCOME_I'][C][U]` to be 1, you need to set it like:

```
$this->totalMonths = 'OUTCOME';
$key = '_I.C.U';

array_set($array, "{$this->totalmonths}.$key", 1);
```

But... there looks to be something missing in your question. How come this:

```
$this->totalMonths = 'OUTCOME';
$key = 'moved_to_I.C.U';

echo "{$this->totalmonths}.$key";
```

Would output this?

```
OUTCOME_I.C.U
```